# Select Single field multiple times with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to generate a Project wise surface area at each activity from below table PLE

```
Activity    Posting Date    Surface Area  Project
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Shearing     01-04-2013     2.34          A   
Bending      01-04-2013     2.34          A 
Assembly     02-04-2013     2.34          B
PC           02-04-2013     5.34          B  
Infill       05-04-2013     5.34          C
```

I'm trying to do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Project,sum(Project.[Surface Area]) AS TotalShearing 
FROM PLE
WHERE ([Posting Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
  AND (Activity = Shearing)
GROUP BY Project
```

Now I want to display `TotalBending, TotalAssembly` and so on in columns right to `TotalShearing`. But no idea how to get them as WHERE condition is already used for Activity 'Shearing'. This may be simple task, but I'm new to SQL and hence need HELP!

Comment: Can you give the sample Output?

Comment: I want it for all activities. Thanks for quick response. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Project
    ,sum(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Shearing' THEN [Surface Area] ELSE 0 END) AS TotalShearing 
    ,sum(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Bending' THEN [Surface Area] ELSE 0 END) AS TotalBending
    ,sum(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Assembly' THEN [Surface Area] ELSE 0 END) AS TotalAssembly
    ,sum(CASE WHEN Activity = 'PC' THEN [Surface Area] ELSE 0 END) AS TotalPC
    ,sum(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Infill' THEN [Surface Area] ELSE 0 END) AS TotalInfill
WHERE ([Posting Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
FROM PLE
GROUP BY Project
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6d65/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PIVOT` table operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Activity, [Surface Area], project
  FROM PLE
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  sum([Surface Area])
  FOR Activity IN ([Shearing], 
                   [Bending], 
                   [Assembly], 
                   [PC],
                   [Infill])
) AS p;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a28b/8)

---

If you want to do this dynamically for each number of `Activity` you have to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Activity)
                      FROM PLE
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Activity, [Surface Area], project
  FROM PLE
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  sum([Surface Area])
  FOR Activity IN (' + @cols + ')
) AS p';

execute(@query);
```

See this:

- [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a28b/10)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Project,
sum(if(Activity = 'Shearing', Project.[Surface Area],0) AS Shearing ,
sum(if(Activity = 'Bending', Project.[Surface Area],0) AS TotalBending, 
sum(if(Activity = 'Assembly', Project.[Surface Area],0) AS TotalAssembly
FROM PLE
WHERE ([Posting Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)

GROUP BY Project
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing u want is the **"Partition By"** Keyword in SQL.
To be more precise Sum(....) over(Partition by Activity).
That should do the trick.